# How to update directory to look for new files in Python using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

Dear pythonists I have some software.exe executable that is called by a python module. This software.exe creates new files as outputs.
I would like to move one of these files called "whatever.xml' to anotherFolder how can I "refresh" a directory contents? 
The following code only consider the previous state and cannot find the newly generated files.
Thanks

```
subprocess.Popen('sofware.exe')
shutil.copy( 'whatever.xml' , anotherFolder )
```

Comment: You should be able to list the files in that directory again to "refresh". Is this a [mcve]?

Comment: I am missing a previous comment that said "wait until the subprocess finishes". It worked for me. Sure there will be other ways of doing the same.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popen does not block so the files may not be created before you call copy, you can call `.communicate()` or just use `check_call` which wont return until the process completes.

```
subprocess.check_call('sofware.exe')
shutil.copy( 'whatever.xml' , anotherFolder )
```

Comment: I did 
`subprocess.Popen.wait(subprocess.Popen('software.exe'))`
and it worked fine